# How do I embed fully Google map to website

Tags: html, google-maps

I want embed fully Google map into my website. It mean includes search bar in left.

[google map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RTKA.png)

The link directly on browser address bar will be work https://www.google.com/maps/search/Automation+Supplies+Limited/@53.4455454,-7.5863638,8z?hl=en-IE But when I place it in iframe it not work.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/search/Automation+Supplies+Limited/@53.4455454,-7.5863638,8z?hl=en-IE"></iframe>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

This isn't offered by Google.  All you can do is link to Google Maps.

Answer (score 1):

In the google map link that you have mentioned above, open it and click on Menu bar. Choose **Share or embed map** and you may find your html code for website.
Here is an example of your map: `<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m12!1m8!1m3!1d1212742.5438103776!2d-8.069837255079928!3d53.59579689997422!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!2m1!1sAutomation%20Supplies%20Limited!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1573529617789!5m2!1sen!2s" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>`.

Comment: I know that, but I want embed the map includes Menu bar to my website.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the map in your website and put a search bar in the left side, as an alternative, you can use [**Google Maps Platform's Maps JavaScript API**](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) to do this.

Here is a [sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/oaw6j53t/) I made that looks similar to the implementation that you want which is in the image in your link.

In this example, I used the **Maps JavaScript API** to show the map

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 53.467079, lng: -6.719628},
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
    },
  });
```

and use the Google Maps **Places API library** to put the Autocomplete 
`var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);`
as a search mechanism on the map.

Hope this helps.